# Redirect Back to Current Page After Sign in Using Python in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, redirect

I am currently working on a Google App Engine application using Python that requires user authentication. I am trying to redirect the user back to the previous page they were viewing after signing in to their Google account (it is currently redirecting to the homepage).

**Code Snippet:**

```
 def login_required(handler):

    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            return self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))
        else:
            return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_login
```

**Handler:**

```
class MyHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def options(self):
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Accept'
        self.response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET'

    @login_required
    def get(self):
        template_values = {

        }

        #the_page = I'm not sure if I'm supposed to pass the user's page here
        the_page = '/index.html'

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), the_page)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

My two questions are:

1) what should I fix in order to redirect the user to the page they were last viewing?

I tried:

```
self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.referer))
```

instead of

```
self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.url))
```

That didn't fix the issue.

2) Is the_page in 'MyHandler' supposed to be the default page if redirection fails?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suspect your confusion stems from the fact that regardless of the URL contained in a request reaching your `get()` method it always gets the same answer - the one for `the_page`. Check your app's logs - they contain the exact URLs requested and allow you to confirm if the post-login redirection works correctly (which I suspect happens OK, otherwise I'd expect you to see a 403 or some similar permission/access error)

Comment: I'd leave aside the `@login_required` decorator for now and 1st confirm your `get()` properly serves the pages you're expecting it to. Then move on to authentication.

Comment: And keep the redirection with `self.request.referer` on the side - you'll likely want that if you use `@login_required` on `POST` requests. If/when you get there...

Comment: The `GET` request is correct, it is serving the right page

Comment: Exactly. Your problem is not the redirection, it's the fact that the reply from the handler always contains the same thing (it is always built from the `index.html` template, making it look like the homepage) regardless of which page is actually requested.